# Create divs from Array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have different strings in my array. Is it possible to create a divs like 
`<div id="results"></div>` for each array element in my HTML page?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure, simple example without using any frameworks or libraries:

```
var cars = 'Saab,Volvo,BMW,GMC,Nissan,Ford'.split(',');
for (var c in cars) {
    var newElement = document.createElement('div');
    newElement.id = cars[c]; newElement.className = "car";
    newElement.innerHTML = cars[c];
    document.body.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

You can take a look at how this works using jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/geNNa/

Answer (score 26):

Yeah, using a `for` loop:

```js
var arrayVariable = ['one','two','three'],
    arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;

for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  $('<div class="results" />').text(arrayVariable[i]).appendTo('body');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or slightly more jQuery-fied:

```js
var arrayVariable = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

$.each(arrayVariable, function(index, value) {
  $('<div />', {
    'text': value
  }).appendTo('body');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You could do this in vanilla JavaScript too, if you'd prefer:

```js
var arrayVariable = ["one", "two", "three"];
var arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;
var temp;

for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.className = 'results';
  temp.innerHTML = arrayVariable[i];
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(temp);
}
```

It's worth considering where the `id` is coming from; if more than ***one*** element is to be produced by this `for` loop, it might be better (depending on where, and how, the `id` is assigned) to use a `class` instead, as I did in both of my suggestions, as the `id` **must** be unique within the document.

While this answer was written quite a while ago, I felt it worth updating to reflect the possibilities offered by the (relatively new) `Array.prototype.forEach()`, which iterates over each element of a given array, and applies a function for each iteration. For example, given the HTML:

```
<ul id="fruits"></ul>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var fruitsList = document.getElementById('fruits'),
    li = document.createElement('li'),
    clone;
['apples','bananas','cranberries'].forEach(function (fruit, index) {
    clone = li.cloneNode();
    clone.textContent = index + ': ' + fruit;
    fruitsList.appendChild(clone);
});
```

Resulting in the output:

```
<ul id="fruits">
    <li>0: apples</li>
    <li>1: bananas</li>
    <li>2: cranberries</li>
</ul>
```

```js
var fruitsList = document.getElementById('fruits'),
  li = document.createElement('li'),
  clone;
['apples', 'bananas', 'cranberries'].forEach(function(fruit, index) {
  clone = li.cloneNode();
  clone.textContent = index + ': ' + fruit;
  fruitsList.appendChild(clone);
});
```

```html
<ul id="fruits"></ul>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
  - [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).
  - [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName).
  - [`Element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className).
  - [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML).
  - [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).
  - [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode).
  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).
- jQuery:

  - [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo).
  - [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text).

Answer (score 3):

A Basic For Loop + jQuery should do it. Just replace `body` with a selector for the container you want to add the divs to. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/vjdGM/) showing the technique in use.

```
var myCars=new Array("Saab","Volvo","BMW");

for(var x=0; x<myCars.length; x++){
    $('body').append('<div id="' + myCars[x] + '">' + myCars[x] + '</div>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var results = ['result 1', 'result 2', 'result 3'];

$.each(results, function(idx, value){
  var newdiv = $('<div>',{class: 'results', text: value});
  $('body').append( newdiv  );
});
```

used [`$.each()` <sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), and also changed the id to class since id needs to be unique.

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/FuPF7/