# How to create an array of divs with content?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to create an array of nested divs, in which I only need to change 3 values when writing the divs to the document (html).

My divs look like this:

```
<div class="item">
   <div class="item-h"> <a class="item-anchor" href="1_water_bottle.html">
     <div class="item-image"> <img class="item-image-first" src="images/img_1_water_bottle.png" alt="">
       <div class="item-meta">
         <h2 class="title">Water Bottle 1</h2>
         <span class="item-arrow"></span> </div>
     </div>
     </a> </div>
</div>
```

I need to create an array of about 50 items, and then use the `document.write` function to write 4 of those arrays for each page, as a section for "similar stuff".

I searched on stackoverflow, and came up with :: [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886144/create-divs-from-array-elements#answer-5886725) :: , which explains how to create an array in javascript, and then found another script that uses the document.write function.

The script uses an array of categories, to populate a form selection. And it does so, but using an array : (`var categories = new Array("a1", "a2", "a3", ...)` and so on.

```
for(var hi=0; hi<categories.length; hi++) 
        document.write("<option value=\""+categories[hi]+"\">"+categories[hi]+"</option>");
```

Could I use these two scripts to populate a section with 4 items from the array of the divs?

If so, then how could I do it? I know it can be done in php, but don't know if this can be done in javascript.

I tried, and created this array in notepad++, but the code wasn't recognized as a string, per array element...

```
var array_divs = [ 
$('<div class="item">
     <div class="item-h"> <a class="item-anchor" href="1_water_bottle.html">
     <div class="item-image"> <img class="item-image-first" src="images/img_1_water_bottle.png" alt="">
     <div class="item-meta">
     <h2 class="title">Water Bottle 1</h2>
     <span class="item-arrow"></span> </div>
     </div>
     </a> </div>
 </div>') ,

$('<div class="item">
     <div class="item-h"> <a class="item-anchor" href="1_water_bottle_2.html">
     <div class="item-image"> <img class="item-image-first" src="images/img_1_water_bottle_2.png" alt="">
     <div class="item-meta">
     <h2 class="title">Water Bottle 2</h2>
     <span class="item-arrow"></span> </div>
     </div>
    </a> </div>
</div>')

]
```

Trying to populate the section, with selective items from the array, for example:

`document.write(array_divs[1],array_divs[2]);`

I haven't tried this, but since notepad++ didn't treat my div as a string, I had to search again... but couldn't find any info regarding this.

Thanks for any help.

-

Comment: I would seriously look at a different approach to what you are trying to accomplish. Using js to create and insert elements in the DOM is a much cleaner and less error prone way to do this than just `document.write`-ing a whole bunch of HTML code.

Comment: I would look into an MVC (or, as I currently use, Backbone js(MV*)) pattern in combination with a Javascript templating engine. Instead of storing the divs into an array, it may be better to store the View objects. By keeping these "View" objects in memory, you're not only keeping the DOM elements (divs), but you can also access the properties/methods of the stored Views directly. I assume that the three values you speak of are variable data; they can be re-fed to the View object at any time (representing a Model), resulting in an automatic re-rendering of the View on the screen.

Comment: @ElGavilan :  was going to define the array in a js file, but for getting the array into the page, I need to use the document.write within the html page only. Cause it doesn't write on it's own even if I place the js file where I need the content to be displayed. ... Also, how can I use your method? I only know that dom is a region in html where all the javascript files are placed, and the scripts are processed by the browser. It's usually in the head tag, but can also be placed just before the body tag closes... How could I achieve this in dom? Thanks

Comment: DOM is the collection of all of the HTML/XHTML elements on your page. This collection can be programmatically manipulated by javascript. There are various ways to do this; one of the easiest and most common ways is via JQuery. You also might want to look into Kim's suggestion of using MVC and a javascript templating engine, or something like AngularJS.

Comment: @KimGysen : Yes, I could do that, but I might need an example. My url encoding is `1_item_A.html, 1_item_B.html, 2_item_C, 2_item_D` where I've numbered my categories into 1,2,3 and kept the item name as it is... Please could you provide an example of your method, so that it becomes easy to access the values via the array? Thanks

Comment: @ElGavilan & : I know about jquery, and have been learning it since last year summers! But I don't know how I could use ElGivilan's method via jquery. I don't intend to use complex methods, though I could understand jQuery, but I don't know how to create arrays in jquery or how to create the divs content with them.

Comment: The best way to learn an MVC framework in my experience is by watching tutorials and jumping right into it. It seems troublesome at first (to me it did), but once you get used to it, it is really awesome to work with. Backbone has also a dependcy on jQuery. Personally, I wouldn't develop any web application without it anymore, but to each his/her own. I cannot give you a quick example, best is to get started with it. I'm afraid that if you continue the path you are going now, you may be going into spaghetti hell anyhow. Check out Requirejs for modular programming and dependency management.

Comment: @KimGysen: I'm not keen on learning a new framework altogether! I know bits of javascript and jquery... but won't be able to learn the MVC scripting you're mentioning.... Could there be any way to do this in javascript or jQuery?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that! But for now, I think I'll try and get this done via xml and jquery! I already have a xml file with the info, guess I'll just parse that instead, and use a function to return the 3 values via the xml instead! Will search/write for the code for that tomorrow... thanks again!

Comment: Hi! I tried solving my problem via XML today, but couldn't get the script to function... Please could you provide any help? Or should I ask for this question on a separate post? Thanks! 
My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezUL2/