# JavaScript adding to an array and displaying it in html

Tags: javascript, arrays, geocoding

I'm working with a piece of code from Google, trying to alter it such that instead of windows.alerting the LT/LN coordinates, the coordinates get saved in an Array that can then be displayed in a table of some kind.

```
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    var cords = []; //my array
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        window.alert("Coordinates:" + results[0].geometry.location); //current alert           
        cords.push(results[0].geometry.location); //adding to an Array            
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm very rusty with JS, so i'm not even sure if it is being stored in Array. I tried a number of ways to display the Array to the screen but nothing worked, i'm not sure if that is because nothing is being stored in the array or because i'm not display the array correctly.

**Explicitly put: Any ideas on how to store these coordinates in array & how should I go about display this array on screen? Cheers.**

Comment: you can use `console.log(cords)` and open developer tools (f12) to see the output, but it *looks* fine. As for adding them to html there are a legend of possible solutions; here is a vanilla JS implementation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886144/create-divs-from-array-elements

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display an array in HTML:

HTML:

```
<div data-cords></div>
```

JS:

```
var html = '';
cords.forEach(function(cord) {
   html += cord + '<br>';
});
document.querySelector('[data-cords]').innerHTML = html;
```

Otherwise, you can print the array in your developer console:

```
console.log(cords);
```

Or, if you want to `alert` it, you can use the same construction as above:

```
var alertMessage = '';
cords.forEach(function(cord) {
   alertMessage += cord + '\n'; // new line character
});
alert(alertMessage);
```

Comment: Why have you chosen to use a custom html attribute ?

Comment: I prefer to use data attributes to hook up behaviour to HTML elements with JS instead of id's or class names. Scales better, single responsibility (no CSS/JS interference). Also, it's a regular `div` element with a data attribute, which has been standard stuff in browsers for ages

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```js
var cords = [];
function searchAddress() {
  var addressInput = document.getElementById('address-input').value;
  document.getElementById('address-input').value = "";

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geocoder.geocode({address: addressInput}, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      var myResult = results[0].geometry.location; // reference LatLng value
      
      cords.push(myResult);
      
        document.getElementById('add-loc').appendChild(generateList(cords));
      
    } else { 
    // warning message
    alert("The Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);

  }
 });

}

function generateList(array) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        // Set its contents:
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    // Finally, return the constructed list:
    return list;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  
<body>
    <div>
       Enter address <input type="text" id="address-input">
       <button onclick="searchAddress();">Search</button>
    </div>   
    <div id="add-loc"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: @Dansmith does it help you?