# Place button iterating a list

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, web

I want to create these buttons:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button">Linear algebra    </button>
<button type="button">Calculus I    </button>
<button type="button">Basic Mechanics    </button>
<button type="button">Mechanics1    </button>
<button type="button">Mechanics2    </button>
<button type="button">Mechanics3    </button>
<button type="button">Mechanics4    </button>
<button type="button">Mechanics5    </button>

</body>
</html>
```

And I was wondering if there is an option to do it with a function for when the list is even longer. 
My idea is to create the following list:

```
var subjects=["Linear algebra","Calculus I","Basic Mechanics","Mechanics1","Mechanics2","Mechanics3","Mechanics4","Mechanics4"]
```

And iterate it with a for loop and then create the button with the result of every element in the list. Is this possible?

Comment: yes it is possible :p

Comment: Pretty much this but with buttons instead of divs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886144/create-divs-from-array-elements

Comment: Either use a **framework** to handle this type of things (e.g. AngularJS or other versions) or write a small look that creates elements into the DOM based on an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Array forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate through the array, use [**createElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create the buttons and [**appendChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to append them to the DOM where needed.

```js
var subjects=["Linear algebra","Calculus I","Basic Mechanics","Mechanics1","Mechanics2","Mechanics3","Mechanics4","Mechanics4"]

subjects.forEach(function(item){
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.innerHTML = item;
    document.body.appendChild(button);
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful! I can see that I do not need to call the function because it operates directly. Then, should I place the script where I want the buttons to be? What if I want all my js functions in a separated file? Is there an option to make the function callable? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to call it as a function, declare a function and place the code inside of it. How you separate your code is up to you. Just make sure you reference the files containing your code on the page you want to use them on.

Comment: And can you show me how to call the function? The onload method only works inside body or img...

Comment: If you know how... Thank you a lot!