# Show unique values of an array only once in divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following script to randomly shuffle values in an array:

```
function shuffle(array)
{
  var m = array.length, t, i;
  while (m > 0) 
  {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }
  return array;
}

var keywords = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"];

shuffle(keywords);
```

Now what I am trying to do with those randomly shuffled krxwords: I have 24 divs and I want to display one result in each of those divs:

```
<div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="grid g1" data-row="0" data-column="0"><h1>Show value 1 of array</h1></div>
    <div class="grid g2" data-row="0" data-column="1"><h1>Show value 2 of array</h1></div>
    <div class="grid g3" data-row="0" data-column="2">...</div>
    <div class="grid g4" data-row="0" data-column="3">...</div>
    <div class="grid g5" data-row="0" data-column="4">...</div>
    <div class="grid g6" data-row="4" data-column="0">...</div>
    <div class="grid g7" data-row="4" data-column="1">...</div>
    <div class="grid g8" data-row="4" data-column="2">...</div>
    <div class="grid g9" data-row="4" data-column="3">...</div>
    <div class="grid g10" data-row="4" data-column="3">...</div>
</div>
```

How could I do this?

In addition, there is a link belonging to each number, e.g. link 1 for value 1. How can I show these corresponding links in the div?

I really appreciate your help, I do not even know what to look for on the internet since I'm new to JS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create divs from Array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886144/create-divs-from-array-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use JS vanilla and loop with `forEach` on each div with `grid` class and giving the `innerText` property the corresponding keyword after the shuffle.

```js
var keywords = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"];

(function() {
  shuffle(keywords);
  
  const grids = document.querySelectorAll('.grid');
  
  grids.forEach(function(grid, i) {
    grid.innerText = keywords[i];
  });
})();

function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length,
    t, i;
  while (m > 0) {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }
  return array;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="grid g1" data-row="0" data-column="0">
    <h1>Show value 1 of array</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="grid g2" data-row="0" data-column="1">
    <h1>Show value 2 of array</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="grid g3" data-row="0" data-column="2">...</div>
  <div class="grid g4" data-row="0" data-column="3">...</div>
  <div class="grid g5" data-row="0" data-column="4">...</div>
  <div class="grid g6" data-row="4" data-column="0">...</div>
  <div class="grid g7" data-row="4" data-column="1">...</div>
  <div class="grid g8" data-row="4" data-column="2">...</div>
  <div class="grid g9" data-row="4" data-column="3">...</div>
  <div class="grid g10" data-row="4" data-column="3">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery functions such as `.text()` work on all elements you give them. So `$(".grid").text()` will run on however many elements `".grid"` selects.

If you pass a callback function, then the result of the callback will be used - in this case to fill the element's text.

The callback function receives the element's index as the first argument, which works out nicely with your array's indexes.

```js
var keywords = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"];

$(function () {
  shuffle(keywords);
  
  $(".grid").text(function (i) {
      return keywords[i];
  });
})

function shuffle(array)
{
  var m = array.length, t, i;
  while (m > 0) 
  {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }
  return array;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="grid g1" data-row="0" data-column="0"><h1>Show value 1 of array</h1></div>
    <div class="grid g2" data-row="0" data-column="1"><h1>Show value 2 of array</h1></div>
    <div class="grid g3" data-row="0" data-column="2">...</div>
    <div class="grid g4" data-row="0" data-column="3">...</div>
    <div class="grid g5" data-row="0" data-column="4">...</div>
    <div class="grid g6" data-row="4" data-column="0">...</div>
    <div class="grid g7" data-row="4" data-column="1">...</div>
    <div class="grid g8" data-row="4" data-column="2">...</div>
    <div class="grid g9" data-row="4" data-column="3">...</div>
    <div class="grid g10" data-row="4" data-column="3">...</div>
</div>
```

---

For what it's worth, your function `shuffle` could be replaced by a random [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
keywords.sort(function () {
    return Math.random() >= 0.5;
});
```

In modern JS (aka "ES6") this can be shortened with an [arrow function](https://caniuse.com/arrow-functions):

```
keywords.sort(() => Math.random() >= 0.5);
```

and the jQuery call can also be streamlined in modern JS:

```
$(function () {
  $(".grid").text(i => keywords[i]);
})
```